# How to create a circle through OOP without using the Canvas?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, ecmascript-6

I implemented a Circle class with properties:

- x - the initial value of the x coordinate
- y - the initial value of the y coordinate
- radius - values of width and height
- color - fill color

And the method: "`draw()`" - draws on the screen an element that is described by the specified properties

**But why is that the method does not work, and there is no circle ?**

```js
class Circle {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }

    draw() {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.width = `${this.radius}`;
        div.style.height = `${this.radius}`;
        div.style.border = "1px solid;";
        div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
        div.style.color = `${this.color}`;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
}
let options = {
    x: 1500,
    y: 100,
    radius: "100px",
    color: 'red'
};
let circle = new Circle(options);

circle.draw();
```

Comment: Your code does not add the created `<div>` to the DOM.

Comment: You have to append your div to the DOM to show the element

Comment: add div to appendChild but method still does not work

Comment: You have to put units ("px") on the width and height. If you just set them to numbers, they'll be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you constructor, you didn't use the object you passed, instead you used several parameters:

Instead of this:

```
constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
```

Use this, when passing an object as `options`:

```
constructor(options) {
```

And in the constructor, use the `options` parameter to get the values:

```
Object.assign(this, {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    radius: 100,
    color: 'red'
}, options);
```

Use [**`Object.assign()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), to set your options. The 2nd parameter acts as **set of default options**, the 3rd will be the **actual options passed** to the constructor. The **default options will be overridden with the actual options** passed to the constructor.

*Credits to [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy)*

---

To position your circle as it would have `x` and `y` coordinates, set it's position to `absolute` and set the `left` and `top` properties, like `x` and `y`:

```
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
div.style.top = `${this.y}px`;
```

To set the circle's fill color, set the `backgroundColor`, instead of the `color` property:

```
div.style.backgroundColor = `${this.color}`;
```

...as the `color` property **sets the color of the text, not the background of the element**.

```js
class Circle {
    constructor(options) {
        Object.assign(this, {
          x: 100,
          y: 100,
          radius: 100,
          color: 'red'
        }, options);
    }

    draw() {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
        div.style.top = `${this.y}px`;        
        div.style.width = `${this.radius}px`;
        div.style.height = `${this.radius}px`;
        div.style.border = '1px solid;';
        div.style.borderRadius = '50%';
        div.style.backgroundColor = `${this.color}`;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
}

const options = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    radius: 100,
    color: 'red'
};

const circle = new Circle(options);
circle.draw();
```

Comment: Or `Object.assign(this, options)`

Comment: @Pointy, thanks, that's correct, I'm gonna update it as I prefer that too.

Comment: Yes and probably should be `Object.assign(this, defaults, options)` of course

Comment: @Pointy although in code meant for production, I would use a properly documented `const DEFAULTS = {...}` as a set of default values, but in this case for the sake brevity, I didn't use that here. What's your stance on this?

Comment: Sure, that's a fine idea. My point was that it's good not to completely rely on client parameters setting all the properties that the working code depends on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to append `div` to DOM and as your defined constructor you need to pass four parameters, but you pass object so try this :

```js
class Circle {
    constructor(opt) {
        this.x = opt.x;
        this.y = opt.y;
        this.radius = opt.radius;
        this.color = opt.color;
    }

    draw() {
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.width = this.radius + 'px';
        div.style.height = this.radius + 'px';
        div.style.border = '1px solid;';
        div.style.borderRadius = '50%';
        div.style.backgroundColor = this.color;
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
}
let options = {
    x: 1500,
    y: 100,
    radius: 100,
    color: 'red'
};
let circle = new Circle(options);

circle.draw();
```